# Is it possible to set the value of an environmental variable on an agent/node from a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to pass the value for an environmental variable that set on the node under "Node Properties"

Example: I have GIT_BRANCH environmental variable set on the node the value is passed to that variable is ${BRANCH_Z}. ${BRANCH_Z} value comes from a pipeline script like so

```
pipeline {  
 agent none;
 parameters {
   string(defaultValue: "master", description: 'Branch to build', name: 'BRANCH_Z')
}
environment {
   GIT_BRANCH = "${params.BRANCH_Z}"
}
```

But when I run this I get back params.BRANCH_Z as the value not master.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can set dynamic values for environment variables within the `environment` block during pipeline declaration. You can, however, do this for default values in the `parameters` block during pipeline declaration.

If you want to set a dynamic value for an environment variable, you will likely need to set it within the `env` map inside the pipeline during execution, such as:

```
stages {
  stage('Foo') {
    steps {
      env.GIT_BRANCH = params.BRANCH_Z
    }
  }
}
```

I also believe that one or more plugins may automatically assign that specific environment with a value, so overwriting it is safer anyway.

Comment: Can you explain `BRANCH_Z`?

Comment: It is the name of the asker's parameter. You should ask him or her why it was named `BRANCH_Z`.

Comment: @ MattSchuchard Oh.